# Find and Replace in MySQL - Exact Match Case Only

Tags: mysql

i want to search for the exact match and replace it.

i have tried this

```
update [table_name]
set
    [field_name] = replace([field_name], '[string_to_find]', '[string_to_replace]');
```

this above query is not doing what i want. it is replacing the word, even it is in middle of another work. but **i want to replace - exact match cases only.**

**update:**

i want to replace A to APPLE and E to Elephant

when i ran 1st query it is replacing A to APPLE and then when i am running again it is replacing

E to Elephant and APPLE TO APPLELEPHANT (apple has e at the end) but i didn't want to do this

EG

```
CODE 

A    
E
C
```

when i run this *update table1 set code = replace(code, 'A', 'APPLE');*

it is converting as

```
CODE 

APPLE    
E
C
```

it is OK!

and when i ran this  *update table1 set code = replace(code, 'E', 'ELEPHANT');*

```
CODE 

APPLELEPHANT    
ELEPHANT
C
```

**APPLE IS ALSO CONVERTING** i don't want like this

Thank you!

Comment: According to your description, your query _is_ replacing exact matches wherever it finds them (including the middle of words). Do you mean you only want to replace the match if it is a distinct word? If so, please specify the exact criteria for the expected match.

Comment: yes he is. like "hi i am heretoday"  repl today with tomorrow would leave it alone

Comment: @DrewPierce In your example, 'today' is a part of the word 'heretoday'. The result would be 'hi i am heretomorrow' which sounds like exactly the results that the OP is currently getting.

Comment: correct. he doesnt want that

Comment: @GeorgeCummins i have updated my question. please check it ones

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
UPDATE [table_name] 
SET [field_name] = '[string_to_replace]'
WHERE [field_name] = [string_to_find];
```

Comment: When it "fails" you need to be more specific. Error? Didn't do anything?